# Keep Application synchronised with cookie on httprequest android

Tags: android

I have successfully retrieved and stored a cookie in my sharepreference. Using the post method below:

```
public static void postData() throws JSONException {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Constant.CONNECTION_URL);
        ResponseHandler<String> resonseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login",""));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass",""));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost,resonseHandler);

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
            success = obj.get("success").toString();
            fname=obj.get("fname").toString();

            if (success.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                //connection successfull
                login_success_status.SavePreferences("login_success_status", success);
                login_success_fname.SavePreferences("login_success_fname",fname);
                List<Cookie> cookies = ((AbstractHttpClient) httpclient).getCookieStore().getCookies();
                CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

                cookie_name.SavePreferences("cookie_name",cookies.toString());
```

Now i need to do another call to webservice using another url and the cookie stored in the sharepreference. How can i make a call using http with this cookie attached and how can i keep a cookie alive in my application.

Comment: Do you need the same `Cookie` throughout the app?

Comment: yes i need to use this cookie in another http call

Comment: Store your cookie in an `Application` class and then retrieve whenever you want to use them. Once you close the app it won't be available any longer but when you start your app the next time call your web service in the background to get them and store them in the `Application` class again.

Answer (score 0):

what happen exactly when you login to server , One session is created between client and server and you get that session id in cookies. This session id is valid for some period of time which is set by the server once you logout from the application this session is expired and no more valid for next call. If you are using net banking you may know when you stay idol for sometime after login. When you click any option after some time it will say your session is expire and redirect to the login page. Same scenario is here once you out from the application previous cookies are not useful once it is expire.So there is no benefit to store cookie persistently in sharedpreferences.

1) Declare `List<Cookie> cookies`  as `public static`

```
public static List<Cookie> cookies ;
```

2) No need to write cookies in sharedpreferences

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        if (cookies != null) {
            int size = cookies.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                httpclient.getCookieStore().addCookie(cookies.get(i));
            }
        }
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Constant.CONNECTION_URL);
        ResponseHandler<String> resonseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
```

3) update here

```
if (success.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                //connection successfull
                login_success_status.SavePreferences("login_success_status", success);
                login_success_fname.SavePreferences("login_success_fname",fname);
cookies = ((AbstractHttpClient) httpclient).getCookieStore().getCookies();
```

Comment: is the cookie automatically stored for the application ? if i closed the application and open it again will the cookie still remain stored ?

Comment: In your case cookie does not require to store persistently because we need same cookie when application is alive, I mean login session is alive on web so once application closed that cookie will expire and will not useful when you restart the application.

Comment: what should i do if i want to make it persistent

Comment: Nikita you don't getting my point is storing cookie persistently is not require here because once you logout from the app same cookie will not accept by the server because once you out/logout from the app that cookie will removed by the server and will not valid for the next call. So try this solution is working with me perfectly

Comment: if i close the application and reopened later will the cookie still be in the application